# Has there been any positive influence in current philosophical thinking which comes from Hans Vaihinger's 'As If'' Philosophy?

Tags: metaphysics, idealism, modelling

Hans Vaihinger- Born: Sep 25, 1852 · Nehren, Germany
Died: Dec 18, 1933 · Halle, Germany
Written works: The Philosophy of 'As if' · Die Philosophie Des ALS OB: System Der Theoretischen, Praktischen Und Religiosen Fiktionen Der Menschen Auf Grund Eines Idealisme
Education: University of Tübingen · Humboldt University of Berlin · Leipzig University · Tübinger Stift

Professor Vaihinger posited that humans cannot determine the underlying structures of reality and should therefore create suppositions about metaphysics that can then be acted on 'as if' they are true. He had many detractors, like the Positivists, and only a few supporters. But he has been credited as the first to propose a process of modelling for philosophical theorizing. Is anyone aware of any influences or serious work derived from his suppositions?

Comment: See [Fictionalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictionalism/#BriHisOve) : [Arthur Fine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Fine) discusses [fictionalism](http://faculty.washington.edu/afine/Fictionalism.pdf) with ref to Vaihinger.

Comment: See also [Hartry Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartry_Field) for [Fictionalism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictionalism-mathematics/).

Comment: @mauroAllegranza- Thanks much will look into your suggestions.CMS